# bash: Reads a text file and removes specific characters if they exist

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I try to get rid of the last slash in the URL, but only if it exists.
any ideas?

```
tail -1 /var/script/string.txt | grep -oP '(?<=expanded_url":")[^"]+'
```

response:

```
https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers/
```

The desired output:

```
https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead `(?:(?!/?").)+` to check what is on the right is not an optional forward slash followed by a double quote. If that is not the case, then take any character and repeat that 1+ times.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/agQhL1/1)

For example:

`echo 'expanded_url":"https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers/"' | grep -oP '(?<=expanded_url":")(?:(?!/?").)+'`

**Result**

```
https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with `awk` you could try following too.

```
var="https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers/"
echo $var | awk '{sub(/\/$/,"")} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now, only for explanation purposes.

```
var="https://research.checkpoint.com/ramnits-network-proxy-servers/"    ##Creating a variable in shell which has value as OP mentioned.
echo $var | awk '{sub(/\/$/,"")} 1'         ##Sending echo output to awk command here. In awk command using sub to substitute / which comes in end of line with NULL.
                                            ##awk works on method of condition and action, so mentioning 1 is making condition TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default
                                            ##Printing of line/variable value will happen.
```

***EDIT:*** By seeing your attempt trying to add 1 more solution to avoid many commands combinations here(this will read only last line of Input_file and come out of command then since I have put `exit` in it).

```
tac Input_file | awk 'FNR==1 && /xpanded_url\":\"/{sub(/\/$/,"");print;exit}'
```

***EDIT2:*** Adding single `awk` command here, in some `awk` at its `END` block we can't fetch last line in some we can so adding both kind of solutions whichever works for people.

```
awk 'END{if($0 ~ /xpanded_url\":\"/){sub(/\/$/,"");print}}'  Input_file
OR
awk '{val=$0}END{if(val ~ /xpanded_url\":\"/){sub(/\/$/,"",val);print val}}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @bugnet17, please try my EDIT command also once, if that helps you.

Comment: Thae `tac` could be avoided if you simply do the processing in the `END` block.

Comment: @tripleee, yes I thought that too but I remember Ed's comment that some of awk do not support it, I will add it too now. Moreover we need NOT to read whole file in this case since I am exiting after reading last line.

Comment: @tripleee, sir, added both kind of `awk` in solution(one solution in which their awk support reading last line in end block and another where it do not).